# Is this output from dpkg-query -L openjfx what it should be?

Tags: java, eclipse

I am struggling to run openjfx and getting desperate. I thought I was ok troubleshooting in linux and java, but I've never been stuck for such a long time.

As usual with linux, there is lots of guidance but it's all conflicting and complicated. Each error message I get features in tons of low-scoring questions on several sites in the stackexchange network. Each question has a handful of conflicting and low-scoring answers which are brief, incomplete and vaguely related to my problem. A half of the questions are then closed because they "have been answered" when they haven't. I tried openjfx 11 with openjdk 11 but resolving one error only allowed me to get another one.

Stack exchange requires specific questions so here is my question: **Below, I showed my  output from dpkg-query -L openjfx. Is it what it should be?**

I made a separate clean installation of xubuntu 18.04.3 LTS and followed [these steps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56166582/8957293) but no luck. I then tried following [this](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/OpenJFX/Using+an+IDE#UsinganIDE-JDK-8Only:Deletejfxrt.jar(ormoveittoadifferentdirectory)). It's full of stuff I don't understand, but gives me unrelated google results.

I am trying to run [this code](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/get_started/hello_world.htm). In my Run configuration I have `--module-path /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/lib/ --add-modules javafx.controls` in my VM arguments - I cannot remember where I got it from. I am currently getting this:

```
Unrecognized option: --module-path
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

Here is the dpkg output which people tend to use to troubleshoot.

```
$ dpkg-query -L openjfx
/.
/usr
/usr/bin
/usr/lib
/usr/lib/jvm
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/javafxpackager
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/javapackager
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/lib
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/man
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/man/ja_JP.UTF-8
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/man/ja_JP.UTF-8/man1
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/man/ja_JP.UTF-8/man1/javafxpackager.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/man/ja_JP.UTF-8/man1/javapackager.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/man/man1
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/man/man1/javafxpackager.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/man/man1/javapackager.1.gz
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/openjfx
/usr/share/doc/openjfx/TODO.Debian
/usr/share/doc/openjfx/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/openjfx/copyright
/usr/share/man
/usr/share/man/man1
/usr/bin/javafxpackager
/usr/bin/javapackager
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/javafx.properties
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/jfxswt.jar
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/lib/ant-javafx.jar
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/lib/javafx-mx.jar
/usr/share/man/man1/javafxpackager.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/javapackager.1.gz
```

**Shouldn't the above not be more [like this](https://superuser.com/questions/1419623/cannot-get-javafxopenjfx-to-work-with-openjdk-8-using-netbeans-8-2)? I thought I should see stuff like javafx.controls listed whether it's openjfx 8 or newer.**

Here is another command people tend to put in questions like mine

```
$ java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_242"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-8u242-b08-0ubuntu3~18.04-b08)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.242-b08, mixed mode)
```

Comment: Hot stuff, 15 views in three months. But I did find a [workaround that worked: installed oracle JDK](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56104/how-can-i-install-sun-oracles-proprietary-java-jdk-6-7-8-or-jre). But it just a workaround, not a solution, so I'm not adding it as an answer, unless I'm told to. Lesson: it was a mistake to stick to "everything open" for such a long time.

Comment: Too late to edit above comment to clarify it. In other words, I regret not installing Oracle JDK earlier. I was refusing to do it because it was not "hardcore open source/free" and I think it was a mistake to get so hung up on principles. In hindsight, Oracle JDK would have been perfectly fine for first steps in javafx and I could be trying to run openjfx alongside learning javafx itself.

Answer (score 0):

I, too, would expect `dpkg-query -L openjfx` to [list the files contained in the package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/amd64/openjfx/filelist) only.

But rather than answering your question, I would rather help solving your problem: It looks like you are trying to mix the concept of modules introduced in Java 9 with Java 8. I recommend sticking to Java 11, which is available in Ubuntu 18.04. Download the javafx-sdk manually.

Have this script as an example which works on my system:

```
#!/bin/bash
wget --no-clobber -O javafx-sdk.zip https://gluonhq.com/download/javafx-11-0-2-sdk-linux/
unzip -n javafx-sdk.zip
mkdir -p helloworld
cat > helloworld/HelloWorld.java <<EOF
package helloworld;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class HelloWorld extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.setText("Say 'Hello World'");
        btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                System.out.println("Hello World!");
            }
        });

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(btn);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 250));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
EOF
/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac --module-path javafx-sdk-*/lib --add-modules javafx.controls helloworld/HelloWorld.java
/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java --module-path javafx-sdk-*/lib --add-modules javafx.controls helloworld.HelloWorld
```

I do not understand your comment regarding 'it was a mistake to stick to "everything open" for such a long time', though.

Comment: Thanks. WRT sticking to 11: I originally tried both 8 and 11 with no luck, and I did try not to mix them up etc. My only comfort is that issues with openjfx are fairly widely acknowledged. WRT the comment I put under my OP: too late to edit it, and I don't want to mess up the chronological order of my comment and your answer, so I added another comment under my OP to clarify the first one.

Comment: Now I understand your comment. However, you may want to be aware that Oracle stopped bundling JavaFX with Java 11. Unless one sticks with Java 11, they will experience the problems you ran into – regardless of the Java implementation supplier.